# WP_User_Query by meta_value with Number returns nothing

Tags: users

When querying users with `WP_User_Query` by `meta_value` like '23432' (as string or integer) it returns nothing. If searched by text like 'admin' it returns all users where `meta_value` equals 'admin'.

```
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query(
        array(
            'number' => 1,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'customer_id',
                    'value'   => '23432',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    $users = $user_query->get_results();
```

The `meta_value` = '23432' is in the wp_usermeta table at `meta_key` = 'customer_id' and by search in MySQL it returns the right entry.

Comment: Does it work, when you remove `'number' => 1` part? Why do you use `LIKE` as compare method?

Comment: Dosen't work. I also tried '=' and without meta_query at all. Doesn't work as work. Only when I query a text-string like  'admin'.

Comment: have you tried ( after `compare` ) to append `'type' => 'NUMERIC'`?